# Django: Shuffle a queryset randomly and access object fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have a list

```
[<Upload: 33-bb6f5d9a98604450>, <Upload: 35-bb6f5d9a98604450>, <Upload: 30-bb6f5d9a98604450>, <Upload: 31-bb6f5d9a98604450>, <Upload: 34-bb6f5d9a98604450>]
```

which has been generated by

```
ques = list(sorted(Upload.objects.filter(unique_id=tdetail), key=lambda x: random.random()))

<Upload: 33-bb6f5d9a98604450>
```

here Upload is the model and `33-bb6f5d9a98604450` is the slug of model upload
how can we extract `Upload` model values from this list

heres my views

```
def platform(request,e,slug):
article = get_object_or_404(Article,e=e)
tdetail=get_object_or_404(test_detail,test_id=article)
if Platform.objects.filter(user=request.user,test_key=article).exists():
    platform=get_object_or_404(Platform,user=request.user,test_key=article)
    slugs = platform.list
    for obj in slugs:
        ques = Upload.objects.filter(slug=obj.slugs)

     #Upload.objects.filter(slug=slugs)
else:
    ques = list(sorted(Upload.objects.filter(unique_id=tdetail), key=lambda x: random.random()))

    platform=Platform()


    platform.user=request.user
    platform.test_key=article
    platform.list=ques
    platform.save()


return render(request, 'articles/platform.html',{'ques':ques})
```

here is my model of platform

```
class Platform(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(User)
test_key=models.ForeignKey(Article)
list=models.CharField(max_length=2000)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s(%s)" % (self.user,self.id_apply)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'test_key',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for obj in ques:
    print obj.slug_field
```

Can access the object fields by iterating through the list generated. I can see that you are trying to shuffle the queryset randomly. Maybe you can do this:

```
ques = Upload.objects.filter(unique_id=tdetail).order_by('?')
```

which in turn will be a queryset and you can use it as usual.
Or maybe you can use shuffle from random, and do it using python:

Assuming **ques** is a list:

```
from random import shuffle
    shuffle(ques)
```

For the error, Instead of this:

```
slugs = platform.list
```

do this:

```
import json
slugs = json.loads(platform.list)
```

which will return a list of slugs, after that instead of the loop:

```
 ques = Upload.objects.filter(slug__in=slugs)
```

Comment: Using a for loop as mentioned in the answer. You iterate through it and access it like : obj.slug

Comment: yes i want to shuffle the query set and for one user the ques will be shuffled only once and then i am storing that pattern in the database so that if user refreshes the url it won't get a new shuffled ques.......

Comment: So is your question answered?

Comment: `slugs = platform.list
        for obj in slugs:
            ques = Upload.objects.filter(slug=obj.slugs)`       this is what i did here platform is the model that stores the list .....it gives the error......'unicode' object has no attribute 'slugs'

Comment: It will be better if you post the entire view in the question for the better understanding, or part of it which is in question.

Comment: "slugs = platform.list",  returns a list of slugs I presume?

Comment: no i am storing the list as character platform is the model in which there is a char field as list so platform.list just gives me that entire row

Comment: Which means , this is wrong: for obj in slugs:
        ques = Upload.objects.filter(slug=obj.slugs),     since what you are doing is actually iterating over a string, not a list. you would have to convert it into a list first

Comment: i have added the views please check it out.....first the else statement executes...i have problem in if statement it does not reads  the list

Comment: Convert it into a list of slugs first and then do (in the forloop):ques = Upload.objects.filter(slug__in=slugs)

Comment: Update a sample of platform.list in the question please

Comment: Meaning you are not saving the list field properly. When you save the list field please dump the string and save it like this: json.dumps(list) and then do the save

Comment: Don't shuffle a Django queryset directly, as you will get a
TypeError: 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment

You need to convert to list: shuffle(list(ques))

Comment: Thanks @Dos, I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through your list. Eg

```
for upload in ques:
    print upload.field_name
```

field_name is a column(field) from upload model.

Comment: so how i'll extract the slug values  of this `<Upload: 33-bb6f5d9a98604450>`....here Upload is model name and  ` 33-bb6f5d9a98604450` is slug ......kindly help me

Comment: if slug is the field name in upload modal (for slug). use upload.slug